# How to create Oracle database link with sysdba privilege

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, dblink

I want to:

```
  select * from v$database@standby;
```

*Problem*:

- **standby** is mounted so only a **SYSDBA** user can connect to query it
- I can't find out how to use a **database link** using **SYSDBA** privilege

My goal is to display system information/stats from a standby Oracle database on a web page.

I'm using Oracle APEX. Pages are computed from mod_plsql which runs from an Oracle DB so it is easy to display the result of this kind of query.

Alternative:

- How to select * from "shell script"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, based on the few things I've seen via Google.

To sum up, connecting remotely as sysdba uses authentication via the password file. Database links do not attempt to authenticate this way, they are authenticated in the remote database and not externally.

[Here's a link](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/dblink-as-sysdba,4) to a site that briefly touches upon the subject.

Comment: It's happened again - I have answered my own question, as the link referred to is an Oracle-L post by me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK STANDBY
```

rather than CREATE DATABASE LINK STANDBY. I just tested this from sqlplus / as sysdba and was able to query.